# Get Property names From Objects | JavaScript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have a function which I'd like to take an object as a parameter. I can't afford to have the function check for all the possible names of its properties, so I'm here looking for an easy way to get those values.

```js
function getObjContents(object) {
    let content /* = list of obj's properties */;
    return content;
}
```

For example I can do something like this:

```js
function getObjContents1(object) {
    let content = object;
    return content;
}
// The problem is that I do not want the everything in the object.

obj = {x: 'Help', y: 'needed', z: 'please'}
getObjContents1(obj)

// returns "{ x: 'Help', y: 'needed', z: 'please' }"
```

If I do this:

```js
function getObjContents2(object) {
    let content = [object.x, object.y, object.z];
    return content;
}
// I'd have to know beforehand what the object's property names are
// plus its only giving me what x,y and z are assigned to rather than the names

obj = {x: 'Help', y: 'needed', z: 'please'}
getObjContents2(obj)

// returns "[ 'Help', 'needed', 'please' ]"
```

Is there a way that I can have `obj = {x: 'Help', y: 'needed', z: 'please'}` in a function that returns only the property names?

```js
// returns "['x', 'y', 'z']"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what you want to get exactly. If you want to get the names of teh props from na object you can define a funciton like this.

```
function getPropNames(object) {
  return Object.keys(object);
}
```

likewise you can get values or both too.

```
function getPropValues(object) {
  return Object.values(object);
}

function getPropNamesAndValues(object) {
  return Object.entries(object);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your parse function in parse.js looks like it only has three input parameters - you need to add the fourth input parameter to the exported parse function:

```
let parse = (arguments, cutLength, object, modeOrFourthParameter) => {

your code

}
```